# How to separate JSON fetch data into different divs

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, fetch, innerhtml

I have javascript to fetch json information.  I will be storing this json file locally (I downloaded an example file and added birthdate object for my use example from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users)

I am trying to parse the returned JSON information and post the contents into 2 seperate div's.  I have a json object named "birthdate".  In my script, I have a var set to call today's date named "today".  It prints the date as "05-12" in console, and that is how I have the "birthdate" formatted in JSON as well.  I don't need the year or time.

What I would like is to have the script compare "today" with the json object "birthdate".
If today = birthdate, then I would like to have that entry information displayed in the user-list-today div to appear under the Birthday Today section of the page.

If today does not equal birthdate, I would like to have all other entries displayed in the user-list-future div to appear under the Birthday Future section of the page.

Nothing should be posted in both areas, only one or the other.

Any help that anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.  I will include all of my code below.  The snippet may give error because I have local path to JSON file instead of online version.

Here is my codepen of it codepen doesnt have the birthday JSON object
https://codepen.io/abc-123-webguy/pen/poegaLq

```
JSON file:

<pre>
 [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "birthdate": "05-12",
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
    "street": "Kulas Light",
     "suite": "Apt. 556",
     "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
    "geo": {
     "lat": "-37.3159",
     "lng": "81.1496"
     }
     },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
     "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
     "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
     "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
     }
     },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "birthdate": "05-12",
     "name": "Leanne Graham",
     "username": "Antonette",
     "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
     "address": {
       "street": "Victor Plains",
       "suite": "Suite 879",
       "city": "Wisokyburgh",
       "zipcode": "90566-7771",
         "geo": {
         "lat": "-43.9509",
          "lng": "-34.4618"
        }
       },
       "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
        "website": "anastasia.net",
      "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
       "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
      }
     },
     {
       "id": 3,
   "birthdate": "05-15",
   "name": "Leanne Graham",
   "username": "Samantha",
    "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
   "address": {
      "street": "Douglas Extension",
     "suite": "Suite 847",
     "city": "McKenziehaven",
     "zipcode": "59590-4157",
    "geo": {
    "lat": "-68.6102",
    "lng": "-47.0653"
  }
},
"phone": "1-463-123-4447",
"website": "ramiro.info",
"company": {
  "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
  "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
  "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
}
 },
{
"id": 4,
"birthdate": "05-15",
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Karianne",
"email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
"address": {
  "street": "Hoeger Mall",
  "suite": "Apt. 692",
  "city": "South Elvis",
  "zipcode": "53919-4257",
  "geo": {
    "lat": "29.4572",
    "lng": "-164.2990"
  }
},
"phone": "493-170-9623 x156",
"website": "kale.biz",
"company": {
  "name": "Robel-Corkery",
  "catchPhrase": "Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity",
  "bs": "transition cutting-edge web services"
}
},
{
"id": 5,
"birthdate": "05-16",
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Kamren",
"email": "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca",
"address": {
  "street": "Skiles Walks",
  "suite": "Suite 351",
  "city": "Roscoeview",
  "zipcode": "33263",
  "geo": {
    "lat": "-31.8129",
    "lng": "62.5342"
  }
},
"phone": "(254)954-1289",
"website": "demarco.info",
"company": {
  "name": "Keebler LLC",
  "catchPhrase": "User-centric fault-tolerant solution",
  "bs": "revolutionize end-to-end systems"
}
},
{
"id": 6,
"birthdate": "05-18",
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Leopoldo_Corkery",
"email": "Karley_Dach@jasper.info",
"address": {
  "street": "Norberto Crossing",
  "suite": "Apt. 950",
  "city": "South Christy",
  "zipcode": "23505-1337",
  "geo": {
    "lat": "-71.4197",
    "lng": "71.7478"
  }
 },
"phone": "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
"website": "ola.org",
"company": {
  "name": "Considine-Lockman",
  "catchPhrase": "Synchronised bottom-line interface",
  "bs": "e-enable innovative applications"
}
},
{
"id": 7,
"birthdate": "05-19",
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Elwyn.Skiles",
"email": "Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz",
"address": {
  "street": "Rex Trail",
  "suite": "Suite 280",
  "city": "Howemouth",
  "zipcode": "58804-1099",
  "geo": {
    "lat": "24.8918",
    "lng": "21.8984"
  }
},
"phone": "210.067.6132",
"website": "elvis.io",
"company": {
  "name": "Johns Group",
  "catchPhrase": "Configurable multimedia task-force",
  "bs": "generate enterprise e-tailers"
}
},
{
"id": 8,
"birthdate": "05-22",
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Maxime_Nienow",
"email": "Sherwood@rosamond.me",
"address": {
  "street": "Ellsworth Summit",
  "suite": "Suite 729",
  "city": "Aliyaview",
  "zipcode": "45169",
  "geo": {
    "lat": "-14.3990",
    "lng": "-120.7677"
  }
},
"phone": "586.493.6943 x140",
"website": "jacynthe.com",
"company": {
  "name": "Abernathy Group",
  "catchPhrase": "Implemented secondary concept",
  "bs": "e-enable extensible e-tailers"
 }
 },
 {
"id": 9,
"birthdate": "05-22",
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Delphine",
"email": "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",
"address": {
  "street": "Dayna Park",
  "suite": "Suite 449",
  "city": "Bartholomebury",
  "zipcode": "76495-3109",
  "geo": {
    "lat": "24.6463",
    "lng": "-168.8889"
  }
},
"phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206",
"website": "conrad.com",
"company": {
  "name": "Yost and Sons",
  "catchPhrase": "Switchable contextually-based project",
  "bs": "aggregate real-time technologies"
}
},
{
"id": 10,
"birthdate": "05-31",
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Moriah.Stanton",
"email": "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz",
"address": {
  "street": "Kattie Turnpike",
  "suite": "Suite 198",
  "city": "Lebsackbury",
  "zipcode": "31428-2261",
  "geo": {
    "lat": "-38.2386",
    "lng": "57.2232"
  }
},
"phone": "024-648-3804",
"website": "ambrose.net",
"company": {
  "name": "Hoeger LLC",
  "catchPhrase": "Centralized empowering task-force",
  "bs": "target end-to-end models"
     }
  }
]

</pre>
```

JS Script

```js
// Instantiates a new Request object with provided parameteres. 
const users = new Request("examplejs.json", {
  method: "GET",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
});


// Use the ES6 fetch method to handle the request.
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
fetch(users)
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    // Loop over each user in the response and send it
    // to the renderUser helper.
    data.forEach(user => {
      renderUser(user);
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // If an error is found it will be caught here
    // and can be subsequently handled.
    console.log('Error Found:', error);
  });


// Helper method which renders the user.
renderUser = (person) => {
  // Creates a new element and assigns some class names to it.
  let userContainer = document.createElement("div");
  userContainer.className = "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4";
  
  // Configure the innerHTML and use the JSON object passed in from the
  // request to formulate the data using ES6 template literals.

  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
  if (dd<10)
  {
  dd='0'+dd;
  }
  if(mm<10)
  {
  mm='0'+mm;
  }
  today = mm+'-'+dd;
  console.log(today);

  userContainer.innerHTML = `
    <div class="user">
      <address>
        <strong>${person.name}</strong><br>
        ${person.birthdate}<br>
        ${person.website}<br>
        <a href="mailto:${person.email}">${person.email}</a>
       </address>
     </div>`;

  // Find the ID 'user-list' and append the userContainer to it.
  // This will cause it to display on the page.
  document.getElementById("user-list-today").appendChild(userContainer);
  document.getElementById("user-list-future").appendChild(userContainer);
}
```

```css
    body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.user {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  border-bottom-color: #d5d5d5;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
HTML 

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <style>
        body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.user {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  border-bottom-color: #d5d5d5;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  margin: 5px;
}


    </style>

</head>
<script src="examplejs.js"></script>
<body>

    <h1 style="text-align:center;">Birthday Today</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> 
          <div id="user-list-today"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      
      <h1 style="text-align:center;">======================================================================================================</h1>

    <h1 style="text-align:center;">Birthday Future</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> 
          <div id="user-list-future"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      
      

</body>




</html>
```

Comment: just in case - you can get today's date in a shorter way ```const today = new Date().toISOString().slice(5, 10)```

Comment: Thank you for this tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are appending the **same** node to two different divs. If you look at the documentation to `appendChild` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), you can see this:

```
The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a 
specified parent node. If the given child is a reference to an existing node in 
the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new 
position (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node 
before appending it to some other node).
```

So in your `renderUser` function you should separate today users from future users and append each one accordingly.

As an example, here each user is appended randomly to either list; see the only change near the end of the `renderUser` function: https://codepen.io/maeriens/pen/wvJMjqG

Comment: I appreciate your help!  I made one change to your pen.  I used this as the opening if statement:  if (today === person.birthdate) { and it's working perfectly.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Would I add a second and third if statement to display a message in todays and upcoming if today does not equal to any of the birthday dates (today or upcoming)?

Comment: I don't think so. You would need to know somehow that you _don't_ have any data to check for that condition _after_ the user rendering is done, and unless you use a querySelector or something to check both div item lengths, and seems complicated. Two approaches from the top of my head are a. keeping a global flag starting at ´false´ that you turn ´true´ if any condition is met, or b. separating the 'today' and 'upcoming' (wonder if you would also need 'past'?) into two arrays, and then if they do have items, iterating and rendering users, if they don't, putting the 'no data' message.